# Gravitational eddies across the galaxy?

Tags: galaxy, gravity, space-time, supermassive-black-hole, time-dilation

I read about [natural gravitational eddies](https://phys.org/news/2014-06-gravitational-fields-black-holes-eddy.html) that travel in a wave that black holes have. They also have a strong magnetic field. Does those eddies follow magnetic field lines of the rotating black hole?  Can a galaxies have their own gravitational eddies like a black hole does?

[image]

Comment: Can you link to where you read about "natural gravitational eddies". My guess is that you are talking about gravitational waves, but your question is not very clear.

Comment: This is probably better for the physics board then here, as it has to do with field theory.   Also, your title is wrong.  "Across the galaxy", isn't right, it only (theoretically) happens in dense gravitational situations, such as close to a black hole's event horizon, perhaps a spinning black hole only.  (The article indicates that you have to search in very specific places and they don't actually study black holes, they crunch numbers).   Also, that article was written a year and a half before gravitational waves were detected.  That detection may have changed the discussion in this article.

Comment: But I voted you up anyway cause it was a really fun little article.

Comment: Why would you expect gravity to be affected by the EM field?

Comment: Did you *read* the article? The title has a clue: "gravitational fields around black holes **might** eddy and swirl". The article is chock-full of words such as "conjecture", "theoretical", "might", and "may". And now you're adding conjecture on top of their conjectures on top of conjectures.

Comment: @Muze a tip I have for you is count the question marks.   You have 4 of them and the first one in the title isn't a question.   And, I'd advise you, after you've written your question, to re-read the article and see how many you can work out yourself and only ask what you can't work out.   It's encouraged to keep it to one question per post and to show some effort on your part before asking.

Comment: @userLTK  I deleted one of them. Hope that helps?